# VirtualBox: Additional Network Interface configured in /etc/network/interfaces but can't connect to Internet

Tags: debian, virtualbox

Following [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37122/virtualbox-two-network-interfaces-nat-and-host-only-ones-in-a-debian-guest-on), I configured 2 network interfaces using VirtualBox for a Debian 9 Guest.

1. Host-Only-Adapter without DHCP to give the VM a static IP Address.

   In `/etc/network/interfaces` configured like this:

   ```
   auto enp0s3 
   iface enp0s3 inet static
   address: 192.168.57.5
   network: 192.168.57.0
   netmask: 255.255.255.0
   gateway: 192.168.57.1
   ```

   I can access the VM using SSH from the Host using this IP Address. This interface seems to work as intended.
2. NAT Adapter

   In `/etc/network/interfaces` configured like this:

   ```
   auto enp0s8
   iface enp0s8 inet dhcp
   ```

   I expected to be able to access the Internet from the Host using this interface. It is not working.

Here is the output of `ip a`

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:64:4a:3b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.57.5/24 brd 192.168.57.255 scope global enp0s3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe64:4a3b/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp0s8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:41:71:e2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.3.15/24 brd 10.0.3.255 scope global enp0s8
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe41:71e2/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem with two gateways. Remove gateway from enp0s3

Comment: That solved the problem. Thank you!